# Memcpy a 2-d vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Long story short, I have a 2-d vector that I need to memcpy().  How do I get a pointer to the first element of the data structure?

Also, given that it's in continuous memory, I can just pass in this pointer and the total size, correct?

Would the following code work?

```
vector < vector <int> > vec;
//  .. assume it's populate and built up here
int* ptr = vec[0].data();  // use this pointer
```

Comment: Why "Would the following code work?"? Have you tried it?

Comment: No, it's not contiguous. Sorry.

Comment: @ Mark: from cplusplus.com `Because elements in the vector are guaranteed to be stored in contiguous storage locations in the same order as represented by the vector, the pointer retrieved can be offset to access any element in the array.`

Comment: Here's the URL for my previous comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/

Comment: Just iterate `std::copy`. That's as good as it will get with the double indirection.

Comment: @Logicrat the elements of the outer vector are `vector` objects, which use an additional level of indirection for their data storage.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `memcpy`?

Comment: Ah, yes, you are quite correct. The elements of each *inner* array would be contiguous, but not the whole enclosing array. Good point.

Comment: I need to use memcpy because I want to take this data structure and straight memcpy it over to a GPU buffer for some CUDA processing.  The easiest way is to represent the data on the CPU in the same way as it is on the GPU.  I want just one 2-D pointer to worry about on the GPU.

Comment: If you are dropping into CUDA land you're probably doing it for speedy processing and if that's the case, you don't want a 2D vector in the first place. They are slow due to the lack of locality. Make a 1D vector and manually index the second dimension (`vec[row * numberColumns + column]`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a single 2-D vector, you have a vector that contains other vectors. Each vector, considered individually, has contiguous storage, but they don't adjoin each other - there's no way to do what you want with a single copy.

You can use the [Boost Multi-dimensional Array Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) to treat a single vector as a 2-D one, which would then allow you to get the entire contents at once.

Answer (score 2):

No, only each `vector<int>` has contiguous memory.  So you what something like:

```
vector < vector <int> > vec;
// ...
int** ptr = new *int[vec.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    ptr[i] = &vec[i][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't memcpy the contents because you don't really have a single contiguous array. You have data made up of many parts.

The outer vector manages its internal array. That array is made up of the inner vector objects who each manager their own separate internal arrays of ints. So that's not just one chunk of memory for the whole thing.

To try to visualize it:

```
vector<vector<int>> object
                       |
                       |-----> internal array:
                                            vector<int>object
                                                        |
                                                        |------>  internal array:
                                                                                int
                                                                                int
                                                                                int
                                            vector<int>object
                                                        |
                                                        |------>  internal array:
                                                                                int
                                                                                int
                                                                                int
                                            vector<int>object
                                                        |
                                                        |------>  internal array:
                                                                                int
                                                                                int
                                                                                int
```

Each internal array there exists at a different location in memory, in no way adjacent to each other.

---

However depending on what you're doing and where you need to copy the data do, you might be able to iterate through all the sub-vectors and memcpy each of their contents sequentially to the destination.